How to use custom emoji in telegram bot?
I wanna make a bot that sends some static custom emoji in text. I haven't found any helpful instructions, so I tried to see how it is made inside. I set up a webhook for my test bot and forwarded a message that contained a custom emoji to my bot. There, I found something like this (some info was deleted because it is redundant):
{
    "update_id": 846867202,
    "message": {
        "message_id": 68,
        "from": {
            "id": <my id>,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": "Shkiper",
            "last_name": "Desna"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": <my id>,
            "first_name": "Shkiper",
            "last_name": "Desna",
            "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1728164235,
        "text": "some emoji \ud83e\udd2a in text",
        "entities": [
            {
                "offset": 11,
                "length": 2,
                "type": "custom_emoji",
                "custom_emoji_id": "5408846744727334338"
            }
        ]
    }
}

So I used it to make a JSON request:
{
    "chat_id": <my id>,
    "text": "hello \ud83e\udd2a",
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "custom_emoji",
            "offset": 6,
            "length": 2,
            "custom_emoji_id": "5408846744727334338"
        }
    ]
}

saved it to file mess.json and sent it using cURL:
curl https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot token>/sendMessage --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST --data @mess.json
But in the end, I got a message that contained only a regular emoji , not the custom emoji that was in the original message.
How can I make a bot sending custom emoji?

According to the Telegram Bot API

Custom emoji entities can only be used by bots that purchased additional usernames on Fragment.

Looking further you can find e.g. Github | Help send custom emoji where it's described like this

You can buy a username on Fragment, pay 5000 TON to make it assignable to a bot, and bot will be able to use Premium emoji.

The fragment.com about site seems to indicate the same (without mentioning the exact costs)

You can upgrade your collectible username to assign it to a Telegram bot. To upgrade, assign the username to a bot on Fragment like you would for any other account and pay the one-time fee when prompted.


Wait, 5000 TON? You mean the currency that costs €5 for 1 TON? Do I need to spend €25 000 just to make a bot able to send emoji? Or did you mean another TON?

Yes, that TON. As in The Open Network. And yes - if the claims about 5000 TON are true - that would come out at around 24k € currently + the costs for a collectible username on Fragement if you don't already own one
